# Forget already paired device - web-bluetooth

Tags: javascript, web-bluetooth

I am working on web-bluetooth to connect a Web-App with BLE device. I have the connections  now, I am looking how can I unpair a device.

I have looked into the official web-bluetooth documents
https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetooth-getdevices haven't find much about it.

Can anybody suggest something on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

What a coincidence! I am currently working on adding a new `forget()` method on BluetoothDevice so that web developers can revoke permission access to a paired BluetoothDevice.

```js
// Request a Bluetooth device.
const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({ acceptAllDevices: true });

// Then later... revoke permission to the Bluetooth device.
await device.forget();
```

- Spec PR: https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/pull/574
- Chromium CL: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1302328

Note that this experimental functionality is currently available in [Chrome 101](https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/commit/f100253a8279ef71a9ce84430744a4b951b98bc2) and requires users to enable the `chrome://flags/#enable-web-bluetooth-new-permissions-backend` flag.

You can try my sample at https://bluetoothdevice-forget.glitch.me/

Comment: Note that `forget()` doesn't actually unpair the device if it has been bonded at the OS level.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am hoping it must be working by now. I would definitely try to use it.

Comment: I have another question. How can I fetch Central deviceName? I tried BLE.deviceName at Arduino but it doesn't give me the name. Do I have to configure it somewhere in javascript.

Comment: Web Bluetooth doesn't allow you to get Central device name (.e.g the Bluetooth adapter of the device your web page is running on) but you can get Arduino device name from Web Bluetooth with `device.name` where `device` is the object you got from `navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice(...)`